# Mongodb: Remove subdocument depending on expression in aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm executing an aggregation query on a mongo collection. At a particular stage in the pipeline I would like to remove a subdocument from the results if a certain expression results *false*.

This is the query at the point where I wish to remove a subdocument.

```
db.getCollection('[module].[virtualwarehouses].supplies').aggregate([
    {
        $match: { 
            $or: [ 
                { artNr: "ART01ds" },
                { GTIN: "GTIN0001" }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
       $lookup: {
           from: '[module].[virtualwarehouses].warehouses',
           localField: 'wId',
           foreignField: '_id',
           as: 'warehouse'
       }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$warehouse'
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
           from: '[module].[virtualwarehouses].warehouses',
           localField: 'warehouse._id',
           foreignField: 'cIds',
           as: 'warehouseP'
       }
    },
    {
       $unwind: {
            path: '$warehouseP',
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                {'warehouse.isDel' : false},
                {$or: [
                    { 'warehouseP.isDel' : false },
                    { 'warehouseP' : { $exists: false } }
                ]},
                {$or: [
                    { 'warehouse.subs' : { $elemMatch: { sKey: "localhost" } } }, 
                    { 'warehouseP.subs' : { $elemMatch: { sKey: "localhost" } } }        
                ]}
            ]
        }
    }
])

------------ RESULT ---------------
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5922eae4f576274033147127"),
    "GTIN" : "GTIN0001",
    "status" : 0,
    "stock" : 2,
    "wId" : ObjectId("5922e378c4352e2b3ccc7b65"),
    "warehouse" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5922e378c4352e2b3ccc7b65"),
        "name" : "Warehouse 2",
        "pId" : "Test Company",
        "type" : 0,
        "source" : 0,
        "cIds" : [],
        "isDel" : false,
        "isEnabled" : true,
        "srcSettings" : {
            "dataSource" : 0,
            "ftpUrl" : "ftps.test.com",
            "ftpDir" : "\\\\serv-s1\\importer",
            "ftpFile" : "test.csv",
            "dropImport" : true
        },
        "subs" : [ 
            {
                "sKey" : "localhost",
                "order" : 500000
            }
        ]
    },
    "warehouseP" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5922e441de7c2c0eaca93e9b"),
        "name" : "Warehouse Combo",
        "pId" : "Test Company",
        "type" : 1,
        "source" : 0,
        "cIds" : [ 
            ObjectId("5922e263c4352e2b3ccc7b64"), 
            ObjectId("5922e378c4352e2b3ccc7b65"), 
            ObjectId("5923f49ef5762740331fadd5")
        ],
        "isDel" : false,
        "isEnabled" : true,
        "srcSettings" : null,
        "subs" : [ 
            {
                "sKey" : "fakeSubscriber",
                "order" : 500000
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In this query I look for supplies in a collection that match an article/GTIN number. The I do 2 lookups to get the warehouse this available article belongs to. (Warehouses can obviously contain many supplies, hence we choose to make a separate collection for supplies, else the document limit would be exceeded)

The reason I do 2 lookups is because in our data model a warehouse can be a combination of warehouses, so I need to check if the warehouse that contains this article is part of a warehouse group.

Now this is where my problem arises. People can *subscribe* to warehouses and should only retrieve stock information from these subscribed stores. The subscriptions are stored in a **subs** field. (see query result in the code field above)

In the query above, I wish to remove the subdocument warehouseP (parentwarehouse) if its subscription field does not include a certain subscriber. In this case, `localhost`.

What I've tried so far are these:

```
---- attempt 1, does nothing, always true
    {
        $project: {
            warehouseP: { 
                $cond: {
                    if: {'warehouseP' : { "subs": { sKey: "localhost" } } },
                    then: "$warehouseP",
                    else: null
                }
            }
        }
    }
---- attempt 2, results in 
---- errmsg: FieldPath field names may not contain '.'."
{
    $project: {
        warehouseP: { 
            $cond: {
                if: { 'warehouseP.subs' : { $elemMatch: { sKey: "localhost" } } },
                then: "$warehouseP",
                else: null
            }
        }
    }
}
---- attempt 3, results in:
---- errmsg: Unrecognized expression '$elemMatch'
{
    $project: {
        warehouseP: { 
            $cond: {
                if: { 'warehouseP' : { 'subs' : { $elemMatch: { sKey: "localhost" } } } },
                then: "$warehouseP",
                else: null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, to conclude. In the output of the upper query, I wish to remove the field warehouseP (set it to null) because its **subs** field does not contain `localhost`. (this field can already be null, if the warehouse containing the supply had no parent) I've tried the things above, but none worked.

---

Edit, to clarify the situation.

I have 2 collections, one with warehouses and one with supplies. [Data examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch3AN.jpg) of the 2 collections.

The supplies collection contains simple objects with a bit of information about the article. It also contain and ObjectId reference to a warehouse.

The warehouse collection contains warehouses with associated data. The key here is that warehouses can be 'virtual', meaning that they are simply a group of other warehouses. If this is the case they have an array of ObjectIds in the field **cIds** (children Ids). Else the warehouse is a real warehouse and it can have associated stock in the other collection. The second important element is the **subs** field. In this field I store data about who is subscribed to this warehouse. The idea here is that people can subscribe to certain warehouses (the logic behind who can and can't subscribe to which warehouse is not relevant here). The should only be able to retrieve information about supplies of articles in warehouses they are subscribed to.

To make it easy I want to have a query that, if I give an article number/GTIN and a subscriber key, returns the supply information. The information should be grouped by 'virtual' warehouses if applicable. By this I mean that if someone is subscribed to a 'virtual' warehouse he should receive the data like so:

```
---- Warehouses that do not have a parent, all end up in this array
{
    "_id" : null,
    "artNr" : "ART01",
    "GTIN" : null,
    "n" : null,
    "p" : null,
    "source" : null,
    "cIds" : null,
    "warehouses" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5922e576f576274033145a3f"),
            "n" : "Supplier Warehouse 1",
            "p" : "Bosch",
            "status" : 0,
            "stock" : 5
        }
    ]
}

---- Warehouses that DO have a parent, should be grouped under a document for every 'virtual' (parent) warehouse
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5922e441de7c2c0eaca93e9b"),
    "artNr" : "ART01",
    "GTIN" : null,
    "n" : "Warehouse Combo",
    "p" : "D Soft",
    "source" : 0,
    "cIds" : [ 
        ObjectId("5922e263c4352e2b3ccc7b64"), 
        ObjectId("5922e378c4352e2b3ccc7b65"), 
        ObjectId("5923f49ef5762740331fadd5")
    ],
    "warehouses" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5922e263c4352e2b3ccc7b64"),
            "n" : "Warehouse 1",
            "p" : "D Soft",
            "status" : 0,
            "stock" : 5
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5922e378c4352e2b3ccc7b65"),
            "n" : "Warehouse 2",
            "p" : "D Soft",
            "status" : 0,
            "stock" : 5
        }
    ]
}

{
    *** potentially many other 'virtual' warehouses ***
}
```

The query I posted above achieves this, but does something wrong in 1 case:
 If someone is subscribed to a warehouse that belongs to a group, that group info is always show. Even if the subscriber is not subscribed to that 'virtual' warehouse.

If I where to use the data above as example, if someone, say `localhost` was subscribed to warehouse 1, but not to Warehouse Combo he would still recieve the data like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5922e441de7c2c0eaca93e9b"),
    "artNr" : "ART01",
    "GTIN" : null,
    "n" : "Warehouse Combo",
    "p" : "D Soft",
    "source" : 0,
    "cIds" : [ 
        ObjectId("5922e263c4352e2b3ccc7b64"), 
        ObjectId("5922e378c4352e2b3ccc7b65"), 
        ObjectId("5923f49ef5762740331fadd5")
    ],
    "warehouses" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5922e263c4352e2b3ccc7b64"),
            "n" : "Warehouse 1",
            "p" : "D Soft",
            "status" : 0,
            "stock" : 5
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want to data to be provided in the data to be provided in the array for warehouses without a parent, since the person is not subscribed to the parent warehouse, and should not be able to receive  that data, like this:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "artNr" : "ART01",
    "GTIN" : null,
    "n" : null,
    "p" : null,
    "source" : null,
    "cIds" : null,
    "warehouses" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5922e263c4352e2b3ccc7b64"),
            "n" : "Warehouse 1",
            "p" : "D Soft",
            "status" : 0,
            "stock" : 5
        }
    ]
}
```

The complete query I have now, that produces the examples above (except for the last, of course) is this (the same as the query at the top of the question, with an additional $group):

```
db.getCollection('[module].[virtualwarehouses].supplies').aggregate([
    {
        $match: { 
            $or: [ 
                { artNr: "ART01" },
                { GTIN: "GTIN001" }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
       $lookup: {
           from: '[module].[virtualwarehouses].warehouses',
           localField: 'wId',
           foreignField: '_id',
           as: 'warehouse'
       }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$warehouse'
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
           from: '[module].[virtualwarehouses].warehouses',
           localField: 'warehouse._id',
           foreignField: 'cIds',
           as: 'warehouseP'
       }
    },
    {
       $unwind: {
            path: '$warehouseP',
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                {'warehouse.isDel' : false},
                {$or: [
                    { 'warehouseP.isDel' : false },
                    { 'warehouseP' : { $exists: false } }
                ]},
                {$or: [
                    { 'warehouse.subs' : { $elemMatch: { sKey: "D Soft" } } }, 
                    { 'warehouseP.subs' : { $elemMatch: { sKey: "D Soft" } } }        
                ]}
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$warehouseP._id',
            artNr: { $first: '$artNr' },
            GTIN: { $first : '$GTIN' },
            n: { $first: '$warehouseP.name' },
            p: { $first: '$warehouseP.pId' },
            source: { $first: '$warehouseP.source' },
            cIds: { $first: '$warehouseP.cIds' },
            warehouses: { 
                $addToSet: { 
                    _id: '$warehouse._id',
                    n : '$warehouse.name', 
                    p : '$warehouse.pId',
                    status: '$status',
                    stock: '$stock',
                    etaStock: '$etaStock'
                } 
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Perhaps the whole approach of this query is wrong and I can be done easier? I have not that much experience with mongoDB. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is actually pretty difficult to say which is the "right" thing to do here without providing a "small" set of sample data and showing at least your approximation of the intended result is. That would go a long way towards actually putting a problem in front of someone else where they can surmise the solution. So it helps to make it as clear to others as you have access to yourself. Without data, we cannot really say that any of the process you are doing is the best thing to do or not.

Comment: Also note your own statement *"else the document limit would be exceeded"*, where this also applies to `$lookup` since it's a basic limitation of the BSON spec. If you cannot possibly reference all the data in a document and therefore put it in other collections, then all `$lookup` is doing is "trying to stuff all that data back into a document". So presumably there would be several measures to actually "filter" the returned results, in order not to break that limit at any point. That's one example of the clarity needed in a question.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you for your interest in the question. I had been planning to ask a question over at codereview to ask if What I was doing was the best way. I was planning on providing a more detailed description of my datamodel there. But since on of the requirements there is that the code is fully functional, and there is still a case in which my query doesn't give the outcome I want, I didn't want to risk posting there and getting downvoted. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @NeilLunn For the `$lookup`: A warehouse can contain quite a large amount of supplies. But in this query I limit the supplies output to those for a certain article number/ GTIN. So, the way I see it, my output will be much lower (only 2 possible supplies per warehouse, if both an existing artNr & GTIN are passed in) I would think this `$lookup` would not result in document limit exceeding. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: What would be best is if you added as much explanation and along the lines I already mentioned to your question. Then when complete you can leave a comment to notify that the information is added. Like I said, it's nice to have samples so as to visualize how it comes together.

Comment: @NeilLunn I've added more information for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Mongo Version 3.2

Using `$filter`

You can use `$filter` to match fields on array followed by `$size + $gt` to project boolean value into `$cond` operator in aggregation pipeline

```
$project: {
    warehouseP: {
        $cond: {
            if: {
                $gt: [{
                    $size: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$warehouseP.subs",
                            as: "result",
                            cond: {
                                $eq: ['$$result.sKey', "localhost"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, 0]
            },
            then: "$warehouseP",
            else: null
        }
    }
}
```

Using `$setIsSubset`

```
{
    $project: {
        warehouseP: {
            $cond: {
                if: {
                    $setIsSubset: [
                        ["localhost"], "$warehouseP.subs.sKey"
                    ]
                },
                then: "$warehouseP",
                else: null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using Mongo Version 3.4

You can use `$in`.

```
{
    $addFields: {
        warehouseP: {
            $cond: {
                if: {
                    $in: ["localhost", "$warehouseP.subs.sKey"]
                },
                then: "$warehouseP",
                else: null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. These all work except if the field warehouseP doesn't exist, or warehouseP.subs doesn't exist. Then I get the errmsg: `$in requires an array as a second argumend, found: missing`. I've been trying to alter the $cond, be I'm not having much succes. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You can write nested `$cond` to check all the values or you can use `$switch` for better readability. Something like `{
    $addFields: {
        warehouseP: {
            $switch: {
   branches: [
      { case: {$eq:[{ $ifNull: [ "$warehouseP", null ] }, null]}, then:null },
      { case: {$eq:[{ $ifNull: [ "$warehouseP.subs", null ] }, null]}, then:null },
   { case: {$in: ["localhost", "$warehouseP.subs.sKey"]}, then:"$warehouseP" }
   ],
   default: null
}
        }
    }
}`. I'll let you work with it. See if you can clean that up a little.